# Hyper-parameter Tuning for a machine learning model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, hyperparameters

Why a hyper-parameter like regularization parameter (a real number) cannot be trained over training data along with model parameters? What will go wrong?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally done to prevent overfitting. Model parameters are trained using the training set. Hyper-parameter tuning is done using a validation set that is (ideally) completely independent of the training data. The final performance should be evaluated on a test set. Typical splits are 80/10/10 or 60/20/20.

If you tune your hypermeters on the training set, you will very likely vastly overfit and suffer a performance hit on the test set.

Try it out! See the difference in performance on your test set when you do hyper-parameter tuning on the training set, vs on a separate validation set.